# Regex for catching word with special characters between letters

Tags: c#, regex, filter, profanity

I am new to regex, I'm programming an advanced profanity filter for a commenting feature (in C#). Just to save time, I know that all filters can be fooled, no matter how good they are, you don't have to tell me that. I'm just trying to make it a bit more advanced than basic word replacement. I've split the task into several separate approaches and this is one of them.

What I need is a specific piece of regex, that catches strings such as these:

```
s_h_i_t
s h i t
S<>H<>I<>T
s_/h_/i_/t
s***h***i***t
```

you get the idea. 
I guess what I'm looking for is a regex that says "one or more characters that are not alphanumeric". This should include both spaces and all special characters that you can type on a standard (western) keyboard. If possible, it should also include line breaks, so it would catch things like

```
s
h
i
t
```

There should always be at least one of the characters present, to avoid likely false positives such as in

```
Finish it.
```

This will of course mean that things like

```
sh_it
```

will not be caught, but as I said, it doesn't matter, it doesn't have to be perfect. All I need is the regex, I can do the splitting of words and inserting the regex myself. I have the RegexOptions.IgnoreCase option set in my C# code, so character case in the actual word is not an issue. Also, this regex shouldn't worry about "leetspeek", i.e. some of the actual letters of the word being replaced by other characters:

```
sh1t
```

I have a different approach that deals with that.
Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: You could use the following [regex](http://regex101.com/r/tS0oT3): `(?i)s[^a-z0-9]*h[^a-z0-9]*i[^a-z0-9]*t`. I wrote it on the fly so maybe you could improve it further.

Comment: To counter things like `sh1t` you could use a character class instead of `i` : `[i1!]`, for `s` maybe `[$s5]`. Note that it may cause invalid alerts.

Comment: Ah, isn't regex [awesome](http://regex101.com/r/eK3vM8) ?

Comment: I wish you posted that as an answer instead of a comment, cause that one actually works.

Answer (score 2):

Lets see if this regex works for you:

```
/\w(?:_|\W)+/
```

Answer (score 2):

`\bs[\W_]*h[\W_]*i[\W_]*t[\W_]*(?!\w)`

- matches characters between letters that aren't word characters or character `_` or whitespace characters (also new line breaks)
- `\b` (word boundrary) ensures that `Finish it` won't match
- `(?!\w)` ensures that sh ituuu wont match, you may want to remove/modify that, as `s_hittt` will not match as well. `\bs[\W_]*h[\W_]*i[\W_]*t+[\W_]*(?!\w)` will match the word with repeated last character
- modification `\bs[\W_]*h[\W_]*i[\W_]*t[\W_]*?(?!\w)` will make the match of last character class not greedy and in `sh it&&&` only `sh it` will match
- `\bs[\W\d_]*h[\W\d_]*i[\W\d_]*t+[\W\d_]*?(?!\w)` will match `sh1i444t` (digits between characters)

**EDIT:**

(?!\w) is a negative lookahead. It basicly checks if your match is followed by a word character (word characters are [A-z09_]). It has a length of 0, which means it won't be included in the match. If you want to catch words like "s*h*i*tface" you'll have to remove it.
( http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html )

A word booundrary [/b] matches a place where word starts or ends, it's length is 0, which means that it matches between characters

[\W] is a negative character class, I think it's equal to [^a-zA-Z0-9_] or [^\w]

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit? What characters fall into the word boundary category? What does (?!\w) mean? If I use this, will it catch things like a_S_H_I_T_a ?

Comment: I think I know where you're going with this, but I've basically decided against this in the beginning. I want "s_h_i_t_h_e_a_d" to turn into "********h_e_a_d" and "s_h_i_t_f_a_c_e" into "********_f_a_c_e". It's all about what people are most likely to do. In any case, this is just version 1, I can update the regex later. One more thing, I've found that S&H&I&T never gets caught, because the server encodes & as &amp;. I don't want to replace the tag in the original text, I want to keep the encoding in words that are ok. So How do I write [^a-z OR this string: "&amp;"] ?

Comment: for catching "&amp;" i think you may use a character class or named grouop. this http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html is nice tutorial to regex

Answer (score 2):

Alright, HamZa's answer worked. However I ran into a programmatic problem while working on the solution. When I was replacing just the words, I always knew the length of the word. So I knew exactly how many asterisks to replace it with. If I'm matching `shit`, I know I need to put 4 asterisks. But if I'm matching `s[^a-z0-9]+h[^a-z0-9]+[^a-z0-9]+i[^a-z0-9]+t`, I might catch `s#h#i#t` or I may `catch s------h------i--------t`. In both cases the length of the matched text will differ wildly from that of the pattern. How can I get the actual length of the matched string?

Comment: Note: You changed `*` to `+`, this will cause that `sh_it` won't be matched. Make sure to use `(?i)s[^a-z0-9]*h[^a-z0-9]*i[^a-z0-9]*t` or even better my [second solution](http://regex101.com/r/zA4nH3) `(?i)[$s5][^a-z0-9]*h[^a-z0-9]*[i1!][^a-z0-9]*t`. Also who cares about the length ? Why don't you just replace it to `****` since it's originally 4 characters.

Comment: That was intentional. I want at least one special character between each character of my word. Otherwise I'd run a high risk of false positives, such as matching "sh it" in "Finish it". I'd rather "sh_it" slips through. As I said, no automated profanity filter is perfect. I've already gotten the length by calling Regex.Matches() and then iterating through the MatchCollection. But your point is very good and I'll consider it.

Comment: You can add `\b` to the begin and end of your expression, this will prevent to match "finish it" :p

Comment: If you have a comment on an answer add a comment. If you have a new question ask a new question.

Answer (score 0):

You want to match words where each letter is separated with the identical non-word char(s).

You can use

```
\b\p{L}(?=([\W_]+))(?:\1\p{L})+\b
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/wZcR1H/1). (I added `(?!\n)` to make the regex work for each line as if it were a separate string.) *Details*:

- `\b` -  word boundary
- `\p{L}` - a letter
- `(?=([\W_]+))` - a positive lookahead that matches a location that is immediately followed with any non-word or `_` char (captured into Group 1)
- `(?:\1\p{L})+` - one or more repetitions of a sequence of the same char captured into Group 1 and a letter
- `\b` -  word boundary.

To check if there is such a pattern in a string, you can use

```cs
var HasSpamWords = Regex.IsMatch(text, @"\b\p{L}(?=([\W_]+))(?:\1\p{L})+\b");
```

To return all occurrences in a string, you can use

```cs
var results = Regex.Matches(text, @"\b\p{L}(?=([\W_]+))(?:\1\p{L})+\b")
    .Cast<Match>()
    .Select(x => x.Value)
    .ToList();
```

See the [C# demo](https://ideone.com/ZLtKKr).

Getting the length of each string is easy if you get [`Match.Length`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.capture.length?view=net-6.0#system-text-regularexpressions-capture-length) and use `.Select(x => x.Length)`. If you need to get the length of the string with all special chars removed, simply use `.Select(x => x.Value.Count(c => char.IsLetter(c)))` (see [this C# demo](https://ideone.com/BjQMtQ)).